# Can a shiny observeEvent wait for another observer that it triggers?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, nested, observers

This is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

my_UI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3, numericInput("Count", "Count", 0)),
           column(3, actionButton("example", "Example"))),
  tags$div(id = 'entry')
)

my_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ch_Count <- reactive({input$Count})
  max_Count <<- 0

  observeEvent(ch_Count(), {
    if (input$Count>max_Count) {
      #Get list of entry to add
        if (max_Count==0) {lstGen <- seq(input$Count)} else {lstGen <- seq(input$Count)[-seq(max_Count)]}
      #Update max_Count
        max_Count <<- input$Count
      #Insert UI
        lapply(lstGen, function(ID) {
          insertUI(
            selector = "#entry",
            ui = conditionalPanel(paste0("input.Count >= ", ID),
                                  wellPanel(fluidRow(column(2,numericInput(paste0("entry_", ID), paste0("Entry ", ID, ":"), 0))),
                                            fluidRow(tags$div(id = paste0("pos_", ID))))
            )
          )
          #2nd-layer reactive
          assign(paste0("ch_Count_", ID), reactive({input[[paste0("entry_", ID)]]}), inherits = T)
          assign(paste0("max_Count_", ID), 0, inherits = T)

          observeEvent(get(paste0("ch_Count_", ID))(), {
            MaxCount <<- get(paste0("max_Count_", ID))
            NowCount <<- get(paste0("ch_Count_", ID))()
            if (NowCount>MaxCount) {
              #Get list of entry to add
                if (MaxCount==0) {lstGen2 <- seq(NowCount)} else {lstGen2 <- seq(NowCount)[-seq(MaxCount)]}
              #Update max_Count
                assign(paste0("max_Count_", ID), NowCount, inherits = T)
              #Insert UI
                lapply(lstGen2, function(ID2) {
                  insertUI(
                    selector = paste0("#pos_", ID),
                    ui = column(2, textInput(paste0("entry_", ID, "_", ID2), label = NULL, value = 1))
                  )
                })
            }
          })
        })
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$example, {
    updateTextInput(session, "Count", value = 4)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4", value = 7)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_1", value = 7)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_2", value = 14)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_3", value = 21)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_4", value = 28)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_5", value = 35)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_6", value = 42)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_7", value = 49)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1", value = 3)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_1", value = 3)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_2", value = 6)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_3", value = 9)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_2", value = 2)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_1", value = 2)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_2", value = 4)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3", value = 6)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_1", value = 6)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_2", value = 12)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_3", value = 18)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_4", value = 24)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_5", value = 30)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_6", value = 36)
  })
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_server)
```

In this App, there is a nested dynamic UI, where:

> 1. The count at the top is to control the number of panels to show
> 2. The first entry at each panel is to control the number of inputs available in that panel.

To facilitate user understanding, I also included an example button, which intends to input some preset data. However, it takes **3 clicks** to update all input values. I suppose this is due to that an `observeEvent` must be finished before another one is triggered, such that in the above code, it makes an attempt to update yet-existent `textInput` boxes, causing the failure to update at one click.

Then, I attempted a workaround as below:

```
my_UI <- fluidPage(
  conditionalPanel("true", numericInput("dummy", NULL, 0)),
  fluidRow(column(3, numericInput("Count", "Count", 0)),
           column(3, actionButton("example", "Example"))),
  tags$div(id = 'entry')
)

my_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ch_Count <- reactive({input$Count})
  max_Count <<- 0

  observeEvent(ch_Count(), {
    if (input$Count>max_Count) {
      #Get list of entry to add
        if (max_Count==0) {lstGen <- seq(input$Count)} else {lstGen <- seq(input$Count)[-seq(max_Count)]}
      #Update max_Count
        max_Count <<- input$Count
      #Insert UI
        lapply(lstGen, function(ID) {
          insertUI(
            selector = "#entry",
            ui = conditionalPanel(paste0("input.Count >= ", ID),
                                  wellPanel(fluidRow(column(2,numericInput(paste0("entry_", ID), paste0("Entry ", ID, ":"), 0))),
                                            fluidRow(tags$div(id = paste0("pos_", ID))))
            )
          )
          #2nd-layer reactive
            assign(paste0("ch_Count_", ID), reactive({input[[paste0("entry_", ID)]]}), inherits = T)
            assign(paste0("max_Count_", ID), 0, inherits = T)

          observeEvent(get(paste0("ch_Count_", ID))(), {
            MaxCount <<- get(paste0("max_Count_", ID))
            NowCount <<- get(paste0("ch_Count_", ID))()
            if (NowCount>MaxCount) {
              #Get list of entry to add
                if (MaxCount==0) {lstGen2 <- seq(NowCount)} else {lstGen2 <- seq(NowCount)[-seq(MaxCount)]}
              #Update max_Count
                assign(paste0("max_Count_", ID), NowCount, inherits = T)
              #Insert UI
                lapply(lstGen2, function(ID2) {
                  insertUI(
                    selector = paste0("#pos_", ID),
                    ui = column(2, textInput(paste0("entry_", ID, "_", ID2), label = NULL, value = 1))
                  )
                })
            }
          })
        })
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$example, {
    print("0>1 starts")
    updateNumericInput(session, "Count", value = 4)
    updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 1)
    print("0>1 ends")
  })

  ch_dummy <- reactive({input$dummy})
  observeEvent(ch_dummy(), {
    if (ch_dummy()==1) {
      print("1>2 starts")
      updateNumericInput(session, "entry_1", value = 3)
      updateNumericInput(session, "entry_2", value = 2)
      updateNumericInput(session, "entry_3", value = 6)
      updateNumericInput(session, "entry_4", value = 7)
      updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 2)
      print("1>2 ends")
    } else if (ch_dummy()==2) {
      print("2>0 starts")
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_1", value = 3)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_2", value = 6)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_3", value = 9)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_1", value = 2)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_2", value = 4)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_1", value = 6)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_2", value = 12)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_3", value = 18)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_4", value = 24)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_5", value = 30)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_6", value = 36)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_1", value = 7)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_2", value = 14)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_3", value = 21)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_4", value = 28)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_5", value = 35)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_6", value = 42)
      updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_7", value = 49)
      updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 0)
      print("2>0 ends")
    } else {}
  })
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_server)
```

where I added a dummy object, whose value is updated each time an `observeEvent` is triggered, and by doing so trigger the next `observeEvent`, hopefully the form will be updated in between the `observeEvents`.

It did not... what is missing?

Any suggestion on that? I would not want to do it by pre-creation of all required boxes.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Comment: I gave up for long... But I just did it. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The version below works for me (replacing the above `observeEvent(ch_dummy(), {})` block). And believe me, I have no idea why this works.
The general idea is to create an extra trigger of a dummy `observeEvent`

**AFTER** the call to `insertUI` (including its `numericInput` components) *and*

**BEFORE** the call to corresponding `updateNumericInput`.

```
observeEvent(ch_dummy(), {
  if (ch_dummy()==1) {
    print("1>2 starts")
    updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 2)
    print("1>2 ends")
  } else if (ch_dummy()==2) {
    print("2>3 starts")
    updateNumericInput(session, "entry_1", value = 3)
    updateNumericInput(session, "entry_2", value = 2)
    updateNumericInput(session, "entry_3", value = 6)
    updateNumericInput(session, "entry_4", value = 7)
    updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 3)
    print("2>3 ends")
  } else if (ch_dummy()==3) {
    print("3>4 starts")
    updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 4)
    print("3>4 starts")
  } else if (ch_dummy()==4) {
    print("4>0 starts")
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_1", value = 3)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_2", value = 6)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_1_3", value = 9)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_1", value = 2)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_2_2", value = 4)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_1", value = 6)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_2", value = 12)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_3", value = 18)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_4", value = 24)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_5", value = 30)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_3_6", value = 36)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_1", value = 7)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_2", value = 14)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_3", value = 21)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_4", value = 28)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_5", value = 35)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_6", value = 42)
    updateTextInput(session, "entry_4_7", value = 49)
    updateNumericInput(session, "dummy", value = 0)
    print("4>0 ends")
  }
})
```